# Design pattern for setup.py to avoid duplicated metadata

Tags: python, easy-install

I have written some python scripts, and embedded some metadata at the top, i.e.:

```
__version__ = '0.6.1'
```

Someone contributed a setup.py, mostly just copying the meta data from the script, so we have:

```
setup(
    (...)
    version='0.4.0',
```

I dislike such duplication a lot, the reason should be obvious above.  Updating the meta data is done by people, and not all people know/remember that it needs to be updated at both places.  Mistakes are bound to happen.  Not to forget the fact that it's also easier to just update the version number one place.  I've attempted to deduplicate the meta data by removing it from the code itself, but ... it's actually referenced in the script (it is a script and it accepts --version and --help after all).  It's also considered "best practice" to embed such meta data in the script.

I can certainly do some tricks to let setup.py read the meta data from the script.  Indeed, it would probably take me less time than to write this question - I more want to know what is considered "best practice".  Is it really considered "best practice" to duplicate this information both in setup.py and in the library/script?  Does there exist some ready-made cookbook boilerplate code for reading the meta data from the script/package itself?  Wouldn't it make sense if the setup method could do this by itself?

Comment: I found some information in PEP 396

Answer (score 1):

You could just import your package and get the metadata from there.

This does assume that your file structure looks like this:

```
root/
    code.py
    setup.py
```

Or

```
root/
    code/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

And either `code.py` or `__init__.py` have the metadata.

```
import os
import sys

__dir__ = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))  # The directory of setup.py, root/
sys.path.insert(0, __dir__)  # Will search __dir__ first for the package

try:
    import code
finally:
    sys.path.pop(0)

setup_args = dict(
    name='code',
    # ...
)

for metadata in ('version', 'author', 'email', 'license'):
    if hasattr(code, '__{}__'.format(metadata)):
        setup_args[metadata] = getattr(code, '__{}__'.format(metadata))

setup(**setup_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2024**: I'm now using setuptools-scm - it automatically sets the version based on the git tag given.  [here is a commit](https://github.com/python-caldav/caldav/pull/364/commits/bf8e70c1ff7ae34279e68c348a1c1454853d0277)

After a bit of research into this, I'll answer myself ...

First of all - apparently there doesn't exist any convention to embed metadata in the script or library itself - I can only guess that it was my own invention to add `__author__`, `__license__` etc into the script.

ATOH, there exists a convention to add `__version__` to scripts and libraries.  [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) describes that this should be automatically set to the VCS revision number on every commit - though it is commonly set to a symantic version number.  [PEP 396](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/) was an attempt to clear this up, but was deferred due to a lack of interesst or time.

Hence when having symantic version numbers in the `__version__` and also supplying the project with a `setup.py`, one will either need to update the version number in two places, or do some tricks to get it auto-updated at one place (or possibly let the VCS autoupdate it both places).

As for myself, I ended up importing the script into the setup.py and reading `__version__` from there -
https://github.com/tobixen/calendar-cli/commit/854948ddc057f0ce7cc047b3618e8d5f6a1a292c